# How do i make image fill 90% screen without losing aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Kindly view the snippet here https://jsfiddle.net/nc7edzck/

I want to display a image on click and it should fill screen irrespective of the screen size without distorting the aspect ratio.

```
.imgclick{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    z-index: 100001;
    max-height: 80%;
}
```

I tried everything but if it works on one screen it distorts for another screen of different screen size.

EDIT: Please try your solution by zooming in and out before posting. Also, we can throw the black strip out its not necessary. I can place it later independently.

```js
var ImageTrigger = false;
$(document).on('click', '.image', function() {
  if (!ImageTrigger) {
    var ImgSrc = $("img", this);
    $("#imgFrame img").attr("src", ImgSrc.attr("src"));
    $("#imgFrame img").attr("alt", ImgSrc.attr("alt"));
    $("#imgFrame img").attr("title", ImgSrc.attr("alt"));

    $("#imgFrame .imgclicktext").html(ImgSrc.attr("alt"));


    $("#imgFrame").css('visibility', 'visible');
    ImageTrigger = true;
    return false;
  }


});

$(document).on('click', 'body', function() {
  if (ImageTrigger) {

    $("#imgFrame").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    ImageTrigger = false;
  }
});
```

```css
.imgclicktext {
  padding: 3px 15px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
img {
  /*transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;*/
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 400px;
  /*! padding: 10px; */
}
.imgclick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 100001;
  max-height: 80%;
}
#imgFrame {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 100000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  visibility: hidden;
  min-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imgFrame">
  <div class="imgclick">
    <img style="margin: 0 auto;display: table;" src="" alt="" title="" class="">
    <div class="imgclicktext" style=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="image" data-content="Not so sweet but ok!">
  <img style="margin: 0px auto;display: table;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f5/Howlsnow.jpg" alt="Not so sweet but ok!" title="Hottie">
</div>
```

Comment: this is the best question i have seen since morning .

Comment: @Mahi me toooooooooooooooooo :D

Comment: min-width: 90%;

Comment: is clipping allowed? otherwise there will be bars on either side of the image (top or sides) when the ratio of the window is different than that of the image (see an old youtube video for an example of this)

Comment: @Mahi Image overflowed from bottom when zoomed in and stayed small when zoomed out. Invalid solution.
KevinB I want to handle both aspects, thats why  am trying to control from height as well as width.

Comment: that... doesn't answer the question (or i don't understand)

Comment: Try clicking the image and then zooming in and out on my fiddle. The pop up image stays in the middle always, but small, i want it to cover 90% screen. Thats it.

Comment: the fiddle doesn't work, so i haven't bothered messing with it. the fact is you can't make an image fill 90% of the screen in both directions while maintaining aspect ratio without clipping, stretching, or having bars of space where the image is not. You haven't specified which of those you want, so it's unclear what solution would fit your needs.

Comment: tried adding jquery? working fine for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126658/discussion-between-unkn0wn-and-kevin-b).

Comment: Great I just ran that snippet at work... Could you please use an image more amenable to debugging like something from https://dummyimage.com/ or http://placehold.it/

Answer (score 2):

Check out this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/nc7edzck/4/

I added a window resize and changed a bit of css:

```
    var height = $('.image').height()*.9;
    var width = $('.image').width()*.9;

    $('#imgFrame img').css('height',height);
    $('#imgFrame img').css('width',width);

    $("#imgFrame").css('visibility', 'visible');

    $(window).resize(function(){
        height = $('.image').height()*.9;
        width = $('.image').width()*.9;
        $('#imgFrame img').css('height',height);
        $('#imgFrame img').css('width',width);
    });
```

Comment: @LegenJery Although this is a perfect solution but it requires some extra calculation which i am trying to avoid. eg. i was initially placing the div tag using  calc(object.height/2+55%) but i switched to a div under div.

Comment: I see. I think this works as well too. I put the hidden image inside the same div as the other image. You may want to play around with the CSS to suit your particular needs https://jsfiddle.net/nc7edzck/5/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `max-width: 90%;` from the .img class and add the same into the .imgclick class. That should do the trick as we want to contain the container instead of the image inside.

[Edit]

Ignore this. Go with LegenJerry's answer with the resize. Its the best solution.

Was going through the css and trying to find a css trick to fix this came up with another solution. Hope this helps. Change the following in your fiddle:

```
img{
/*transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;*/
 max-width: 90%;
max-height: 90%;
/*! padding: 10px; */

}


.imgclick{
position: fixed;
top: 10%;left: 10%;
z-index: 100001;
max-height: 90%;

}
```